# Does printing a ton of data in bash affect processing speed?

Tags: bash, mongodb, logging

I'm inserting some few million records into local MongoDB.

I wasn't sure how to disable logging but the terminal is going crazy outputting tons of data.

Does this actually slow down the insertion or does the terminal "lag" behind what is actually being done?

Comment: Terminal devices are relatively slow and will block. There's a good chance the insertion if slowed down.

Comment: However, the slow part is *updating* the terminal. If the terminal has a large enough buffer, the output you see scrolling by was produced by commands that ran some time ago. The script could complete, and it could take minutes before the output of the script finishes scrolling. You can observe this by running such a script in `tmux`, hitting Control-C, then observing that attaching and detaching is far quicker than waiting for buffered output to finish.

Answer (score 1):

The logging makes it slow. You can buy a new video card or silence the output.

When your `insertscript` gives a lot of output, it can be `stdout` or `stderr`.
You can redirect either of them to a file (or /dev/null). When you redirect, stdout is the default (and has value 1) and stderr is number 2.

```
insertscript > insert.out 2> insert.err
# or
insertscript 1> insert.out 2> insert.err
```

You can also redirect to the current target of another with the `&`:

```
# Stderr also to insert.out
insertscript > insert.out 2>&1 
# or
# stderr to your console
insertscript 2>&1 > insert.out
```

Why not play with the redirection first?

```
echo "Normal output"  >/dev/null
echo "Normal output" 2>/dev/null
rm not_existing_file  >/dev/null
rm not_existing_file 2>/dev/null
#
echo "Normal output"  >/dev/null 2>&1
echo "Normal output" 2>&1 > /dev/null
rm not_existing_file  >/dev/null 2>&1
rm not_existing_file 2>&1 2>/dev/null
```